# AWS ec2-virtualization

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, aws-cli

I have a yes or no question.

I am trying to find out list of instances from our current AWS infrastructure based on their virtualization type.

ex: query to find list of instances which are pvm.

I tried using the query command and filter command. But no gains yet. 
Can we even query to get the virtualization type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ec2 describe instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) list many arguments about the instance, including the virtualisation type

> virtualization-type - The virtualization type of the instance (paravirtual | hvm ).

so you can use the following commands

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?VirtualizationType==`hvm`]'
```

this will return all instances (in the specific region) where virtualisation type is hvm. You can adjust for pvm:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?VirtualizationType==`paravirtual`]'
```

Comment: you can do like `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?VirtualizationType==``hvm``].InstanceId'`

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure out. Hence, I deleted the comment. 
Thank you anyways.